# How to resolve ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast exception on android

Tags: java, android

**This is my error code**

```
public static MangJekApplication getInstance(Context context) {
    return (MangJekApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

**This is my error Log**

```
*java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.alexa.grajek1.MangJekApplication*
```

Comment: Did you set your `MangJekApplication` class as the `android:name` value on the `<application>` element in your manifest?

Comment: I don't know that yet, because I bought this source code and when it runs there is an error like that ..,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `MangJekApplication` should extends `Application`:

```
//other stuffs
public class MangJekApplication extends Application {
    public static MangJekApplication getInstance(Context context) {
        return (MangJekApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
//other stuffs
```

Secondly, you should add `android:name` in `AnroidManifiest.xml` file as following:

```
<application 
   android:name=".MangJekApplication"
   //other stuffs
   ...>
```